# converting a text list (string)to a python list

Tags: python, python-3.x

i see that this question has been asked many a time on this site but i cant find an answer that does what i need.

What i need to do is convert a very long text file (680k lines) to a list in python. the whole text file is formatted as shown below:

```
libertarians
liberticidal
liberticide
liberticide's
liberticides
```

my end goal is to create a system where i replace words with their corresponding dictionary value. For instance dic['apple', 'pears', 'peaches', 'cats']. the below code doesn't work because the list it produces can't be used in a if word in list: statement. i tried it.

```
with open('thefile.txt') as f:
  thelist = f.readlines()
```

this is the entirety of the code with that as the method to retrieve the list.

```
with open('H:/Dropbox/programming/text compression/list.txt') as f:
 thelist = f.readlines()
word = input()
if word in thelist:
 print("hu")
else:
 print("l")
```

output with input 'apple': 
1

in short, the list could be printed but little else.

Comment: the only explanation for your observed behavior is that the lines contain some whitespace on the right (which you never mention) so the `rstrip` in the accepted answer removes that.  There are better ways even with the constraint you do not mention, however.

Comment: @AlexMartelli I didn't know whitespace created problems. I assumed what I saw would be inserted as "word ". If you provide an edit to your answer that fixes the whitespace issue then I will mark it as the answer

Comment: My answer now includes a function using a list comprehension, called `fast` by contrast with the accepted answer's loop approach which I called `slow`  However, Hackaholic's answer suggested a list comprehension well before my own answer did, so I would recommend you accept his answer, not mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
with open('file') as f:
    my_list = [x.strip() for x in f]
```

You can also do your work on the fly insted of storing all the lines:

```
with open('file') as f:
    for x in f:
        # do your stuff here on x
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplest approach:

```
with open('thefile.txt') as f:
    thelist = f.readlines()
```

680k lines means a few megabytes -- **far** from a `MemoryError`, a terror expressed in some comments!-), on any modern platform, where your available virtual memory is **giga**bytes (if you're running Python on a Commodore 64, that's different, but then, I'm sure you have plenty of other problems:-).

The `readlines` method internally does the newline-stripping other approaches need to perform explicitly, and thereby's much preferable (and faster).  And if you need the result as a list of words, there's just no way you can save any memory by a piecemeal approach anyway.

Added: for example, on my Macbook Air,

```
$ wc /usr/share/dict/words
235886  235886 2493109 /usr/share/dict/words
```

so over 1/3rd of the one the OP mentions.  Here,

```
>>> with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f: wds=f.readlines()
... 
>>> sys.getsizeof(wds)
2115960
```

So, a bit over 2MB for well over 200k words -- checks!  Thus, for well over 600k words, I'd extrapolate "a bit over 6MB" -- **vastly** below the amount that might possibly cause a `MemoryError` in this "brave new world" (from the POV of old-timers like me:-) of machines with many gigabytes (even **phones**, nowadays...:-).

Plus, anyway, if that list of words is to be kept as a list of words, there's no way you're going to be spending any less than these few-megabytes piddling amounts of memory!  Reading files line by line and cleverly maneuvering to keep only the subset of data you need from the subset of lines you need it from is, ahem, "totally misplaced effort", when your goal is essentially to keep just about all the text from every single line -- in that particular case (which happens to meet this Q's ask!-), just use `readlines` and be done with it!-)

Added: an edit to the Q makes it clear (though it's nowhere stated in the question!) that the lines must contain some whitespace to the right of the words, so a `rstrip` is needed.  Even so, the accepted answer is not optimal.  Consider the following file `i.py`:

```
def slow():
    list_of_words = []
    for line in open('/usr/share/dict/words'):
        line = line.rstrip()
        list_of_words.append(line)
    return list_of_words

def fast():
    with open('/usr/share/dict/words') as f:
        wds = [s.rstrip() for s in f] 
    return wds

assert slow() == fast()
```

where the `assert` in the end just verifies the fact that the two approaches product identical results.  Now, on a Macbook Air...:

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'import i' 'i.slow()'
10 loops, best of 3: 69.6 msec per loop
$ python -mtimeit -s'import i' 'i.fast()'
10 loops, best of 3: 50.2 msec per loop
```

we can see that the loop approach in the accepted answer takes almost 40% more time than a list comprehension does.

Comment: @ChrisHawley, got it and answered.  Meanwhile, any specific reason you're not accepting this rather than michael pry's technically-inferior answer?  If so, please comment about it, and I'll try, if feasible, to edit this A to satisfy your specific issues -- thanks!

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the added edit to the question, too; The accepted answer really ends up in the same result in the end (of course, without the detailed explanation re the other incorrect information that's been shared here)... Kudos for the effort you put in here, but... ehh!

Comment: @AndrewBarber, good comment -- this is surely going to affect any further dealings of mine with the OP, in that I can assess their tech chops from their unsupported-by-clear-data assertion in their Q's edit, and acceptance of a technically inferior approach producing identical results with more effort.  But, that's fine -- with thousands of messages flooding my email daily, knowing WHO to flag as "send right to spam" for behavior like this is really helpful, and the OP will get on that list next morning PST unless they seriously change their attitude and behavior, and/or **explain** why not!-)

Comment: @AlexMartelli i choose the one i did because yours did what it was suppsoed to but i couldnt use the list past that. the only part of the code that changed was the creation of the list. meaning the only variable is which method was used to get the list. i did not rewrite the code that tried to check items against the list. in this case, that is a dictionary.

Comment: @AndrewBarber see revisions. hopefully that clarifies why i choose the answer i did.

Comment: @ChrisHawley, your edit does suggest a crucial fact that you don't mention: it seems the lines in your text file have whitespace on the right, so the `rstrip` call does become crucial.  Even then, a list comprehension (as in Hackaholic's answer) is faster, as I've shown in an edit to this answer.